# Both find() and findById() in one MongoDB call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to select data from 1 room, but I also want the ids of all other rooms.

I do it with

```
const roomId = req.params.roomId;

Room.findById(roomId).then(room => {
  if (room) {
    Room.find({}).sort({ createdAt: 1 }).then(rooms => {
      if (rooms) {
        res.render()
      }
    }).catch(next);
  }
}).catch(next);
```

but this results in 2 database calls.

Is it possible to limit it to only 1 call?

The room I want has a lot of data which I don't need to extract for the other rooms since I only need their IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all the rooms by .find() and then use [underscore library's](http://underscorejs.org/) [findWhere](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) function to filter what you want out of complete dataset. The underscore library works very well for large datasets also.

Ideally the code should look like below:

```
Room.find({}).sort({ createdAt: 1 }).then(rooms => {
  if (rooms) {
    var filteredRoom = _.findWhere(rooms, {_id: roomId})
    filteredRoom = filteredRoom.pop()
    res.render()
  }
}).catch(next);
```

Comment: Is this the same as `Array.find()`? I would like to avoid including `underscore.js` if possible

Comment: Yes it is somewhat the same. But if you don't want to use underscore.js then try aggregate() in mongodb. I quess it will help you but I am not sure. You can achieve union of queries with it. I don't think of any other way.